# How to leak and free the allocated pointer of a Pin<Box>?

Tags: rust, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

With `Box` I can alloc an object in the heap, then leak its raw pointer. This pointer can later be freed by reconstructing the `Box` object:

```rust
let num = Box::new(100); // alloc in the heap
let leaked = Box::into_raw(num); // leak, get the pointer

// later..

let _cleanup = unsafe { Box::from_raw(leaked) };
```

The code above works fine.

However, things apparently don't work that easy when using `Pin`, since it doesn't have the `into_raw` method:

```rust
struct Pack {
    num: i32,
    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}

let pack = Box::pin( // aloc in the heap, immovable
    Pack {
        num: 100,
        _pin: PhantomPinned,
    },
);

let leaked = // ... what to do here??

// later...

let _cleanup = // ... and here??
```

How to deal with the `Pin<Box>` in the code above?

Comment: I don't think pinning a box makes any sense if you're just gonna get a raw pointer to the underlying memory anyways. `Pin` only makes sense for smart pointers.

Comment: Why do you have a `Pin<Box>` in the first place? And why do you need a raw pointer to it? I smell an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: This pointer will be sent across a C FFI boundary. AFAIK `Pin` will make `Box` immovable, so it's an additional safety guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`Pin` will make `Box` immovable" is in a sense correct, but really all it does is prevent you from moving out of it or getting a mutable reference to it, at least safely. If you want to get a `*mut _` from a `Pin<Box<_>>` you can do

```
let mut pack = Box::pin(
    Pack {
        num: 100,
        _pin: PhantomPinned,
    },
);

let leaked = unsafe { pack.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() as *mut _ };
```

But this is even less safe than just using a `Box` with `into_raw` because the `Pin` could get dropped while the pointer is still being used.

The better way is to just consume the `Pin<Box<_>>` again right away. This way, it doesn't actually enforce anything but it documents the contract that the memory at `leaked` may not be invalidated until its consumed and dropped again by a `Box`.

```
let leaked: *mut Pack = unsafe {
    Box::into_raw(
        Pin::into_inner_unchecked(pack)
    )
};

// ...

let _cleanup = unsafe { Box::from_raw(leaked) };
```

Answer (score 4):

The effects of having a `Pin<Box<T>>` rather than a `Box<T>` (when `T` is `!Unpin`) are:

- You cannot move the `T` anywhere else — but you can drop it by dropping the box or replacing it using [`Pin::set`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.set).
- You cannot obtain an `&mut T` from it, only an `&T` or a `Pin<&mut T>`. (If you could, that would allow moving it by swapping.)

However, **none of this is relevant if you are going to convert to a raw pointer.** `Pin<Box<T>>` is not a specially immovable *value*; it's a *pointer* that allows a different set of operations within Rust's type system. Pinning the `Box` does not change the `Box` itself. Therefore, you might as well stick to plain `Box::into_raw()`, because once you've passed the pointer to foreign code, *the Rust type it used to have doesn't control anything.* If the foreign code decides to move the contents elsewhere then it can do that regardless of what the Rust type system said; in a typical C FFI scenario, **your documentation** should say “Treat this as an opaque pointer and only use these functions to operate on it”, and that's equally valid whether or not `Pin` is used.

If your Rust code *by itself* actually has a use for `Pin<Box<T>>`, and you want to pass that pointer through FFI, then use [`Pin::into_inner_unchecked()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.into_inner_unchecked). That's an `unsafe` function, but it's unsafe just in that it is bypassing the type system, as FFI must anyway. But most likely, your type does not benefit from `Pin` at all.